# Graph Databases vs Relational Databases(Possible applications)

Tags: graphs, databases

Apart from the fact that there isn't really a language as SQL  and they are less standardized , i was wondering (in terms of their applications) where graph databases are (or can be) more efficient than Relational Databases.
More precisely, if there are some specific kinds of Data sets where the graph organization performs better than the Relational one.

Comment: It looks to me like your question is already answered in the Wikipedia page on graph databases: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database. There are further explanations in some of the references linked there, too.  There's little point in us repeating information that's already available in standard resources.  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking here, and to show us in the question where you've looked and what you've found so far.  If your question is already answered on Wikipedia, it's probably worth doing more research before asking, in the future.

Comment: i don't really see in the wikipedia page where it talks about the kinds of dataset where graph dbs performs better(maybe to store data about employees of a society relational dbs are better but there are some actual other application where graph dbs are more efficient?) the question seemed clear to me even without the example.This is neither so clear even in the references (which i read before asking).

Comment: Seriously?  You really couldn't find anything there?  I suggest reading through it again.  1. "Graph databases by design allow simple and rapid retrieval of complex hierarchical structures that are difficult to model in relational systems.".  2. "For instance, a table containing email addresses [..] This operation, known as a join, can be computationally expensive [in relational systems].  [..] In contrast, graph databases [...] For these types of common operations, a graph database (in theory at least) is significantly faster."

Comment: 3. "The true value of the graph approach becomes evident when one performs searches that are more than one level deep. For instance, [...]"  4. "The relative advantage of graph retrieval grows with the complexity of the query. For instance, [...]"  5. "Graph databases are aimed at datasets that [..]. They are especially well suited to [...]"  6. "Graph databases are a powerful tool for graph-like queries, for example [...]"

Comment: Nothing of that , as before your precious copy and paste, is something like " hey i have a startup, we found that graph dbs are awesome if you want to store this kind of information!" or " we have a lab of research in X, graph dbs are optimal for Y!" or either " I know about this algoritm that perform so good in this case". That was what i expected asking this question here.

Comment: I thought that this was a community where one could receive opinions and ideas ( and material) by the users and since graph dbs are something "new" in a certain sense, i bet there are plenty of users with infornations about performances s that are not on wikipedia.

Comment: This isn't a place to receive opinions, to poll for opinions or experience, or to solicit open-ended discussion.  This is a question-and-answer site; it's a place to receive answers to well-specified, focused technical questions.  Also, we expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking and to show us in the question what research you've done, what you found, and why it wasn't suitable.  You might want to take a look at our [tour], our [help/dont-ask], and look around at other questions to get a sense for how the community works.